# How to Clear all forces acting on a scnnode

Tags: swift, xcode, physics, scenekit

Hey i have a ball that gets launched in the air by an Impulse force. The ball node has gravity and etc. but What im trying to do is basically stop the impulse force that originally launched the ball in the air. I know that with Impulse its like a cannon one and done type of thing. but is there a way to just clear all forces on the node except for gravity of course?
Im using scenekit in xcode and SWIFT but will take Objective C answers

```
 Ball.physicsBody?.applyForce(velocity, impulse: true)
```

The line passes through any error indicators in xcode but DON'T's do anything at all unfortunately

```
Ball.physicsBody?.clearAllForces()
```

Comment: As well as `clearAllForces` try setting the `velocity` and `angularVelocity` of the physicsBody to `SCNVector3Zero`

Comment: Wow it works!!! apparently if you want to clear the forces that propelled the node forward so that you can. relaunch the node with a clean slat again. you have to clear there velocity and etc. Unbelievable your freaking great you always answer my questions genius @James P

Comment: keep this in mind though: using @James P's suggestion will freeze the ball for a frame. What I mean is that if the ball is falling it will collect velocity, but if you use this method it will stop gravity for a frame, thus restarting the gravity's velocity. To prevent this you could keep the z velocity when setting velocity, and make sure that the z velocity is less than zero, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Luckily for what im doing when I reset the velocity & angular. The ball is temporarily disappeared from the view just by the nature of the app haha @Pro Blaster

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the physics in SceneKit but I have taught Physics, maybe this will help.

Impulse and force are two different concepts. When you set `impulse: true` you are stating you wish to apply an impulse INSTEAD of a force. Impulse (J) is a change in momentum and is also equal to a force applied over a set interval of time. So:

impulse = force x time

impulse = mass x change in velocity

So when you apply the impulse, you are changing your node's velocity. This would seem to me a one-time deal, effected at the time you invoke `applyForce`. There should be no need to clear the impulse. (Setting `impulse: false` would be another matter entirely, implying a continual force.)